# If $\,\,\frac{x^2}{cy+bz}=\frac{y^2}{az+cx}=\frac{z^2}{bx+ay}=1,$ then show that ....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on the following problem that one of my friends gave me:

If $\,\,\frac{x^2}{cy+bz}=\frac{y^2}{az+cx}=\frac{z^2}{bx+ay}=1,$ then show that $$\frac{a}{a+x}+\frac{b}{b+y}+\frac{c}{c+z}=1$$. I did a problem which was similar to this one but I could not tackle this particular one. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

We have $$x^2=cy+bz\iff ax+cy+bz=x^2+ax=x(x+a)$$

$$\implies\frac1{a+x}=\frac x{ax+cy+bz}\implies \frac  a{a+x}=\frac{ax}{ax+cy+bz}$$

Comment: @learner, can you please validate the Question?

Comment: You solved a different problem than stated. Note the $az+cx$ and $bx+ay$ terms which should be $ax+cz$ and $az+by$ in order for your solution to work. But given the (correct) counterexample given by @Leox I'm guessing you solved the problem as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong. Put $x=y=1, z=-1$.  Then from the first condition  we get the system $$ -a+c=1, \\b+a=1,\\ -b+c=1. $$ It follows $ a= \frac 12,b= \frac 12,c= \frac 32.  $
Then 
$$
{\frac {a}{a+x}}+{\frac {b}{b+y}}+{\frac {c}{c+z}}={\frac {a}{a+1}}+{\frac {b}{b+1}}+{\frac {c}{c-1}}=\frac{11}{3}\neq 1.
$$